# Python - Counting how many factors a number has

Tags: python, list, primes

I have been trying to make a 'Prime Number Checker' that looks like this:

Please enter a number: 7

The factors are:

1

7

7 is a prime number

Try again? Y

Enter a number: 6

The factors are:

1

2

3

6

6 is not a prime number

It has 6 factors

I am stuck on the very last portion, which counts how many factors a non-prime number has (listed as 'num_factors' in the code below). Thank you! *Edited for clarity.

```
def main():
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 2 and 5,000: "))

    def list_factors(x):
        print("The factors of your number are: ")
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
                if x % i == 0:
                    print(i)
    list_factors(num)

    def is_prime(num):
        if num>1:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if (num%i) == 0:
                    print(num, "is NOT a prime number")
                    break
            else:
                print(num, "is a prime number")

        else:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
    is_prime(num)

    def num_factors(x):
        for i in range(1, x + 1):
                if x % i == 0:
                    list = []
                    print("It has", len(list), "factors")
    num_factors(x)


    print()
    again=input("Try again? (y/n): ")
    if again == "y":
        print()
        main()
    else:
        print("Bye!") 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I think your first example should say that 7 *is* a prime number.

Comment: Create functions which return results. Print results from outside of the functions. Once you get that resolved, the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build a list of factors first, instead of iterating at each step.

```
def get_factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors
```

Now you can define your other functions in terms of the list of factors:

```
def is_prime(factors):
    return len(factors) == 2

def num_factors(factors):
    return len(factors)
```

If you want to make your implementation more efficient, I suggest you read up on prime factorization.

Comment: you only need `n//2 +1`

Comment: @JoranBeasley That has the same time complexity so it's a pointless optimization.  If you want to be more efficient you can iterate up to the square root of `n` and for each factor found add its complement also.  Or, as I mentioned, just compute the prime factors/exponents and use those.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def num_factors(x):
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                list = []
                print("It has", len(list), "factors")
num_factors(x)
```

for

```
def num_factors(x):
    list = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                list.append(x)      
    print("It has", len(list), "factors")
num_factors(num)
```

Your number is called `num`, not `x`. Then you should create the factor list outside the for loop and append each factor to the list.

As somebody recommended in the comments, you should print outside of the functions. Also you don't need to check for factors bigger than `x//2`. So I would recommend something like this:

```
def num_factors(x):
    list = []
    for i in range(1, x//2 + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                list.append(x)      
    return facts
facts=num_factors(num)
print("It has", len(facts), "factors")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("Enter number: "))
k=0
for i in range(2,a//2+1):
    if(a%i==0):
        k=k+1
if(k<=0):
    print("Number is prime")
else:
    print("Number isn't prime")
```

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, the only adjustment would be that you would want to append those values that pass `if x % i == 0` which can also be stated `if not x % i:` and you would want to move the empty list outside of your loop. then just return the length of that list.

```
def num_factors(non_prime):
    l = []
    for i in range(1, non_prime+1):
        if not non_prime % i:
            l.append(i)
    return len(l)

print('It has {} factors'.format(num_factors(10)))
# It has 4 factors.
```

*Future References*:

Just to open you to why it would be important to explore built in functions, you could accomplish this using `filter` in one expression

```
def num_factors(non_prime):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: not non_prime % x, range(1, non_prime +1))))
```

As well as with *list comprehension*

```
def num_factors(non_prime):
    return len([i for i in range(1, non_prime +1) if not non_prime % i])
```

You can find information on both at https://docs.python.org/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
# input and validation integer number
try:
    num = int(input(
        "Please enter an integer number between 2 and 5,000 : "))
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an integer number between 2 and 5,000!!!")

# for check number.
# If number is prime it's true
# If number not prime it's false 
# default is true
status = True

print("%d divided by %d" % (num, 1))
for i in range(2, int(num / 2)+1):
    if num % i == 0:
        status = False
        print("%d divided by %d" % (num, i))
print("%d divided by %d" % (num, num))


if status:
    print("%d is prime" % (num))
else:
    print("%d is not prime" % (num))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to capture all the factors, you could use the sub below. If you give it a number like 1024, it returns a list of ten 2's (all the factors)

```
def main():
    x = int(input('Enter a number to find the prime factors '))

    primes = prime_factors(x)

    print(primes)

def prime_factors(x):
    factors = []

    y = 2

    while (y <= x):
        while x % y != 0:
            y += 1
        x /= y
        factors.append(y)

    return factors

main()
```